# Fixed effects in regression model

Tags: r, model, statistics, regression

I am currently working on my master thesis and I have a number of different regression models as well as types of regressions (censor regression, log models etc). For all of these models I would like to include firm fixed effects and year fixed effect (in my data, I have different dependent variables, only one main independent variable, 2 interaction effects and several control variables). I am measuring the effects of CEO narcissism on internationalization with a dataset of different M&A deals of 33 firms (and 70 CEOs)

How do I include now the firm and year fixed effects into all my regression models in R (which exact code do I have to use, if I do not want to create for each firm (33 of them) and each year (40 years) a separate dummy variable?)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Include these variables as factor variables in your regression model formula and R will automatically turn them into fixed effects. Something like `dat$firms <- factor(dat$firms)` and the same with year, and then `lm(depVar ~ mainVar + ... + firms + year, data=dat)` You could also use the `plm` package, if you want the within estimator.

Comment: ok thank you very much! 
another question: I have a lot of missing data, so i would like to do the invMillsRatio and then the heckit command. (i heard that helps). however i do not know how and when exactly to use these commands. do i need to use them for every regression and in what sequence do i use them?

Comment: One important question is: Are you talking about fixed effects in an econometric or statistical sense? Because they mean different things. In this case, it seems that you are referring to the econometric definition of fixed effects. Is that correct?

Comment: yes in an econometric sense